# Save all customers who buy an item online

Tags: solidity, remix

I am writing a contract where I am trying to save the account addresses of customers who buy an item online. I tried it with arrays but it did not work. Can anyone please suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: Please note that all information stored in a smart contract is publicly visible

Comment: Yeah, I want to add a functionality where everyone can see that a specific iteam is owned by some customers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mapping` Data type to store your customer's list with their respective addresses.

Here is simple example:

```
mapping(address => string)public buyerList;

function saveBuyer(string memory item) public returns(bool success){

      buyerList[msg.sender] = item;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mahesh is correct. The easiest way to save items is using a mapping. If you want to save more than only 1 item per customer, you need to create an array of Items and save that array in a map

```
mapping(address => string[]) private buyerList_;

function saveBuyer(string item) 
      public 
      returns(bool)
{
      string[] storage items = buyerList_[msg.sender]; // get reference of array
      items.push(item);                               // push to the end of the array
      returns true;                                   // success
}

function getItems(address _customer)
      public
      view
      returns(string[])
{
      returns buyerList_[_customer];
}
```

You also should make the map private and offer a view function on that map, either using a given address or using msg.sender.

Comment: if you want to use this code, then you have to use pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;